# change the order of json using xslt

Tags: json, xslt

I have a json array..

how to change the order of the json to another.

input json file

```
[
    {
        "fileName": "file1.xml",
        "value": [
            {
                "data1": [
                    {
                        "data2": [
                            {
                                "data3": [
                                    {
                                        "data4": [
                                            {
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fileName": "file2.xml",
        "value": [
            {
                "data1": [
                    {
                        "data2": [
                            {
                                "data3": [
                                    {
                                        "data4": [
                                            {
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                             {
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the input json file if you see tag1,tag2,tag3 keys are changing in each json objects..

so how to change the order of the json to expected below json...

the order should be always tag1, tag2,tag3...

I tried so many ways to do this.. Can anyone give best approach.

Expected output:-

```
[
    {
        "fileName": "file1.xml",
        "value": [
            {
                "data1": [
                    {
                        "data2": [
                            {
                                "data3": [
                                    {
                                        "data4": [
                                            {
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ],
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fileName": "file2.xml",
        "value": [
            {
                "data1": [
                    {
                        "data2": [
                            {
                                "data3": [
                                    {
                                        "data4": [
                                            {
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ],
                                                 "tag3": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: First of all, processing JSON with XSLT mostly makes sense if you use XSLT 3 so the first question, do you use XSLT 3? And the second point, order of properties in JSON is not defined and at least the XDM maps representing JSON objects in XSLT 3/XPath 3.1 don't have any order so depending on the way you approach that you will depend on proprietary extensions to define the order. So which version of which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: Hi Martin..I'm using XSLT 3.0 version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are wanting to change the order of entries in an Object, not in an Array. That's problematic, because object properties are intrinsically unordered.

Saxon has a serialization property to work around this problem. If your stylesheet does

```
<xsl:output method="json" indent="yes" saxon:property-order="tag1 tag2 tag3"/>
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:sequence select="json-doc('my-input.json')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

then it should serialize the JSON the way you are wanting.

Details: https://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters

Note: To use such Saxon extensions, you need Saxon-PE or higher, which requires a commercial license.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `json-to-xml` and `xml-to-json` I think you have some control over the order and can reorder items in a map so, for ease of compactnesss I would use XQuery to run the `transform` functions with an `xsl:sort`:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';


transform(map {
    'source-node' : json-to-xml('[
    {
        "fileName": "file1.xml",
        "value": [
            {
                "data1": [
                    {
                        "data2": [
                            {
                                "data3": [
                                    {
                                        "data4": [
                                            {
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fileName": "file2.xml",
        "value": [
            {
                "data1": [
                    {
                        "data2": [
                            {
                                "data3": [
                                    {
                                        "data4": [
                                            {
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                             {
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]'),
'stylesheet-node' : <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="array[@key = 'data4']/map" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="@key"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="transformed-json-xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($transformed-json-xml, map {{ 'indent' : true() }})"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
})?output
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nzd8bW

As a stylesheet it would look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="json-text" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">
[
    {
        "fileName": "file1.xml",
        "value": [
            {
                "data1": [
                    {
                        "data2": [
                            {
                                "data3": [
                                    {
                                        "data4": [
                                            {
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fileName": "file2.xml",
        "value": [
            {
                "data1": [
                    {
                        "data2": [
                            {
                                "data3": [
                                    {
                                        "data4": [
                                            {
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                             {
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]    
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="array[@key = 'data4']/map" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="@key"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:variable name="transformed-json-xml">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml($json-text)/*"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($transformed-json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```